# How to refactor this code if I need to rate-limit it's execution speed

Tags: javascript, parsing, sleep

I was thinking, I can use a sleep function - but Javascript does not have a sleep function.

How can I slow this down a bit to prevent a Parse rate-limit? I want to execute one (1) `Parse.Cloud.run` method every 5 seconds.

```
$('.website').each(function(i) {
    var website = $(this).text();
    Parse.Cloud.run('getMainEmail', {url: website}, {
        success: function(result) {
        cell.next().text(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Couldn't find email for website: " + website);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Currently this code finds all the websites in the DOM and fires of a TON of Parse requests at the same time - causing it to rate limit me almost immediately.

Comment: Punch [javascript timer](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) into your favorite search engine.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: How can you fit a timer into a loop? I don't understand how that would solve my problem. Did you read the code sample above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use setTimeout and send website as a parameter

```
$('.website').each(function(i) {
    var website = $(this).text();
    setTimeout(function(siteText){
    Parse.Cloud.run('getMainEmail', {url: siteText}, {
        success: function(result) {
        cell.next().text(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Couldn't find email for website: " + siteText);
        console.log(error);
    }
    }, (i + 1) * 5000, website);
});
```

Comment: Why `i + 1`? Shouldn't the first one be handled right away?

Comment: i dont know, maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    //put your parse code in here
}, 5000)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queue to manage the actions:

```
var timer;
var queue = [];
function enqueue(website) {
    queue.push(website);
    if (!timer) {
        handleItem(); // handle the first item right away
        timer = setInterval(handleItem, 5000);
    }
}

function handleItem() {
    var website = queue.shift();
    if (queue.length === 0 && !timer) { 
        // stop the timer
        clearInterval(timer); 
        timer = null;
    }
    Parse.Cloud.run('getMainEmail', {url: website}, {
        success: function(result) {
            cell.next().text(result);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Couldn't find email for website: " + website);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Your original code then becomes:

```
$('.website').each(function(i) {
    enqueue($(this).text());
});
```

---

If you don't mind a slight delay before the first item is handled, you can have a continually running interval and the design becomes simpler:

```
var queue = [];
setInterval(function () {
    if (queue.length) { 
        var website = queue.shift();
        Parse.Cloud.run('getMainEmail', {url: website}, {
            success: function(result) {
                cell.next().text(result);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("Couldn't find email for website: " + website);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
   }
}, 5000);

$('.website').each(function(i) {
    queue.push($(this).text());
});
```